# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled closing ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

When I click on the home icon the drawer opens and then immediately brings me back to my previous activity. I believe that setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) is interfering with the action bar drawer remaining opened.

Is there anything in the code that could be causing this?

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class GenericActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

/** Slide out drawer navigation **/
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_draft);

    // Set up drawer navigation.
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.in_draft_menu_items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // Set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.in_draft, menu);

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuItem statusItem = menu.findItem(R.id.draftStatusMenuItem);
    mChatItem = menu.findItem(R.id.chatMenuItem);
    MenuItem settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.settingsMenuItem);
    final MenuItem refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.refreshMenuItem);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    if (mSearchFieldToggleState == 1) {
        searchItem.setVisible(true);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        // Close the search when mSearchView is not focused. Also, show/hide the refresh menu button depending on the state.
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
                if(!queryTextFocused) {
                    searchItem.collapseActionView();
                    mSearchView.setQuery("", true);
                    refreshItem.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    refreshItem.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        searchItem.setVisible(false);
    }

    if (refreshItem == null) {
        return true;
    }

    // Set this menu item to refresh the league.
    refreshItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener( new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return draftRefreshMenuItem(item);
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.refreshMenuItem).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mSearchFieldToggleState = 0;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();

    // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
    // container view.
    if (position == 0){
        mSearchFieldToggleState = 1;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        Fragment fragment = new DraftSectionFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        Fragment fragment = new MyTeamSectionFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    } else if (position == 2) {
        Fragment fragment = new RostersSectionFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    } else if (position == 3) {
        Fragment fragment = new ResultsSectionFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Handle the query text changing. Submit the query to the filter.
 * @param query
 * @return
 */
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    if (mDraftPlayerAdapter != null && mDraftViewPager != null && mDraftPlayerAdapter.getFragmentReferenceMap() != null
            && mDraftPlayerAdapter.getFragmentReferenceMap().get(mDraftViewPager.getCurrentItem()) != null) {
        mDraftPlayerAdapter.getFragmentReferenceMap().get(mDraftViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getFilter().filter(query);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Handle the query text being submitted - with a return key. Same process as onQueryTextChange.
 * @param query
 * @return
 */
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    onQueryTextChange(query);
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In previous versions of the support library, `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` would always return `false` - make sure you are using the latest version of the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) (or at least version 18 or higher).

This is the latest code from r18 of the Support Library:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item != null && item.getItemId() == ID_HOME && mDrawerIndicatorEnabled) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you see, it will return true if it the item being passed in is the home button (`android.R.id.home` is the same as `ID_HOME`) and `mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` is `true` (its default value).

Comment: I thought about that. That isn't the problem though. I have the same code working on 2 different activities.

Comment: So you've debugged it and `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` is returning true (i.e., you aren't calling `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`)?

Comment: When I set setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) everything works. The drawer icon isn't there though.

Comment: @PeterMerrill - So you've debugged it and `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` is returning true (i.e., you aren't calling `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`)?

Comment: mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) is returning false.

Comment: I have it working if I don't run the if statement. If I just set it to return true no matter what, then it's working. Is that sustainable?

Comment: @PeterMerrill - I've added code on how the r18 `mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected` works. As you can see, it shouldn't be returning false if you are using r18+ of the Support Library, actually hitting the home button, and `mDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` returns true. Check all those things.